# How to know the reason why my docker container exits?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I run my Jenkins as a Docker container with the command below

```
docker run \  
  -u root \  
  --rm \  
  -d \  
  -p 8081:8080 \  
  -p 50000:50000 \  
  -v /data/jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \  
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \  
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

From time to time, the jenkins container will exit. I even can't find it with "docker ps -a" command, so that I can't get any logs for troubleshooting.

Is there any way I can check the reason why a docker container exits like this?

Comment: remove `--rm` flag to let the container not be removed post termination. Then you can use `docker ps -a` followed by `docker logs <container id>` to see why

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to check where it exits from is first creating a yaml file out of that docker run command and then doing a docker-compose up without the -d. this will continue logging all the messages from the container until it exits and maybe will stop there(sometimes it continues to log for those containers that have a restarting problem).
[Read more about the yaml files here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/)

Comment: I think you mean [`yaml`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)

Comment: Yes I have changed it now .. thank you

Comment: Thanks for you information, I will study about it.

Comment: @Adan please do, its must nicer and easier to handle than running these commands .. the intro link is https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/